# How to create a class in which letters from array 1 will turn into letters from the second

Tags: python

I have two arrays

```
w = ["t", "k", "p"]
w2 = ["т", "к", "п"]
```

should work

```
In: "kpt"
Out: "кпт"
```

Comment: just use `str.translate` combined with `str.maketrans`: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_ref_string.asp

Comment: why do you want to create a class for that?

Answer (score 2):

I would use a dictionary instead of lists.

So I would first define a dictionary that would map my letters correctly like:

```
letter_mapping = {
"t": "т",
"k": "к",
"p": "п"
}
```

then, I can make a function that uses this dictionary to translate my words:

```
def translate(word: str) -> str:
    translation = ""
    for letter in word:
        translation += letter_mapping[letter]
    return translation
```

Now if you pass a test like `print(translate('tkp'))` you will get `ткп` back.

---

**[Update]**

If you absoloutly have to use list then I would do something like:

```
w = ["t", "k", "p"]
w2 = ["т", "к", "п"]

def translate(word:str)->str:
    if len(w) != len(w2):
        raise RuntimeError('Two lists dont have matching lengths!')

    translation = ""
    for letter in word:
        translation += w2[w.index(letter)]
    return translation
```

However, I have to mention that in this approach, you have to make sure per letter added to list `w` you have to add its translation in the exact same position in `w2`. If the order of translation in the second list doesn't match the order of letters in first list, this will give you a wrong translation.

Comment: I need to use the lists, like  ['', '', '']

Comment: I updated the answer with the approach that uses lists!